# Null reference error in axis renderer when redrawing Flex chart Axis

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4, adobe

I have an application in which chart properties can be updated on the fly. I am updating my axis renderers for redrawing axis(There are some custom AxisRenderers which is extended AxisRenderer class in SDK). Some times it is throwing a null object error while changing the axis renderers. In [Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/232531) it is asked, but no one suggested a workaround nor solution. I just wanted to know only from where the error stack is starting, From the debugger i found the error is in the line  `if (_bGuttersAdjusted == true &&  chart.chartState != ChartState.PREPARING_TO_HIDE_DATA && chart.chartState != ChartState.HIDING_DATA)` of AxisRenderer.as. Do anyone have a solution? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the most likely problem is that chart is null. Usually, if you don't have the time or debugging knowhow to track down race conditions in Flex, data binding will paper over a lot of null pointer exceptions.

Comment: In the forum post you linked to, the exception was thrown in an `updateDisplayList()` method. You could override that method, and if the chart is null, then re-invalidate the display list using the `invalidateDisplayList()` method (so `updateDisplayList()` will get called again). If it's not null, call `super.updateDisplayList()`. Just a thought, not sure if it'll work. I'd offer more details, but you haven't offered any other than showing us the line of code that causes the problem but give no indication of what class that code is in or what you do to get to that point.